# Was Bitcoin originally designed to be easy to mine?

Tags: difficulty, satoshi

I’ve read that back around early 2009, Bitcoin was so easy to mine that an old laptop could mine hundreds of coins in a day by simply using a CPU. Was this Satoshi’s original idea for how people should mine Bitcoin, or did he try to design the system so that it could eventually be manipulated by GPU and ASIC farms, causing the difficulty to increase significantly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did Satoshi design Bitcoin to be mineable only on specialized hardware, if the goal was decentralization?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/62336/why-did-satoshi-design-bitcoin-to-be-mineable-only-on-specialized-hardware-if-t)

Comment: @m1xolyd1an Yes, should I just delete the question?